# IntelliJ - Can't resolve symbol after adding a label

Tags: metadata, customlabel, intellij

I added a label and came from :

```
doc.addError('vous ne pouvez pas ajouter de PJ');*
```

to :

```
doc.addError(System.Label.Document_messageErrSuppressionPJ);
```

It's fine on dev console, but IntelliJ isn't able to find the Custom Label ;
I tried retrieving metadata but I'm missing something...
Any idea how to resolve this ?
I can delete my project and import it from scratch, but it's a waste of time even if it would do the work..

A screenshot from the error:

[image]

Thanks !

edit: my src file (that doesn't contain CustomLabels ?!)

[image]

edit2 : 
I'm trying to add custom labels by adding it to the package.xml 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try to regenerate the offline symbol table.
Navigate to

> Tools -> Illuminated Cloud -> Generate Offline Symbol Table ... ->
>   Full

And then Reload the Project

Comment: I'm new using IntelliJ, I'll find how to do it and do it, thanks !!

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, I did it and reload but still the issue persists ; is there a way to look at the CustomLabels in this table ?

Comment: I think that you haven't retrieved this Custom Label. You can check it by opening labels -> CustomLabels.labels file in your project scr. Then try to check availability of  Document_messageErrSuppressionPJ. If there is no such label refresh metadata of CustomLabels.labels file and regenerate the offlline symbol table.

Comment: Hummm I think I have not download the Custom Labels, in fact !
I can't it on the src ! I've edited my question !

Comment: Go to Tools -> Illuminated Cloud -> Retrieve Metadata... select Custom as Contents input option. Then select "labels" from the list below and press Retrieve

Comment: Yes !! It did the work !! Sorry for my noobeing, I learnt something today :)

Comment: You're welcome. Have a nice day))